# Whether to omit "davon/daran/dazu/etc" from a sentence like the following?

Tags: sentence-structure

> Du hast den Richter überzeugt, sie zu begnadigen?
>
> or: Du hast den Richter **davon** überzeugt, sie zu begnadigen?

---

> Erinnerst du dich nicht, dass wir einst ein Paar waren?
>
> or: Erinnerst du dich nicht **daran**, dass wir einst ein Paar waren?

---

> Wenn ich mich nicht entschieden hätte, dir zu helfen, wärst du ...
>
> or: Wenn ich mich nicht **dazu** entschieden hätte, dir zu helfen, wärst du ...

---

When a *zu* or *dass* clause follows, I wonder if it is more common to omit "davon/daran/dazu/etc"?

Or, does some grammatical rule determine whether you can leave them out in certain cases but not in the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These **da-** particles (and **hier-** particles, too) have a demonstrative function. You are pointing fingers here. If you feel you don't need to point to something, you can always leave them out. (Hint: *da* translates *there*, *hier* translates *here*, which is the pointing finger.)

This is the case for all your examples. They are correct with or without the particles. The meaning is also the same because you explain the thing in question in the following clause.

But when you aren't explaining the thing in question, things get complicated.

> Er hat etwas **davon** genommen.

*He has taken something **of it**.*

> Er hat etwas genommen.

*He has taken something.*

Both sentences are grammatically right. But the second has no finger pointing to the thing in question. So you can't leave *davon* out here without changing the meaning. Same for all other **da-** particles.

And finally there are sentences in which such a **da-** particle cannot be left out because it drops into the function of an object:

> **Davon** habe ich noch nie gehört.

*I've never heard **of it**.*

> **Damit** geht es los.

***This*** is where it starts.

One could rearrange the German sentences ("*Ich habe noch nie gehört*" and "*Es geht los*") but both the meaning and the structure are changing so let's assume these are completly different sentences.

Comment: Danke! So ... Am I correct in assuming that you **cannot** omit the "davon/daran/dazu/etc" particles if they refer to an element mentioned in a  **preceding** sentence? Whereas you **can** omit them if they refer to an element mentioned in a  **subsequent** clause, (as is the case with all the three examples above)?

Comment: You cannot leave them out when the sentence structure requires an object and the particle functions as that object. "*Wir waren einst ein Paar. Erinnerst du dich nicht **daran**?*" means exactly the same with or without the **daran** because *erinnern* **can** be used with a prepositional object but it doesn't need to.